# Kibana geoip mapping wrong | unable to change index

Tags: logstash, kibana

I got kibana to index my geoip data. The problem is my data is indexed in kibana as:

```
geoip.city_name
geoip.continent_code
geoip.country_code2
geoip.country_code3
geoip.country_name
geoip.dma_code
geoip.ip
geoip.latitude
geoip.location.lat
geoip.location.lon
geoip.longitude
geoip.postal_code
geoip.region_code
geoip.region_name
geoip.timezone
```

To make a map with my data I need the fields to be geo_point. The error I see while trying to build the map is:

```
No Compatible Fields: The "csv" index pattern does not contain any of the following field types: geo_point
```

I found some solutions where I have to change my index from "csv" to something with logstash-*. When I change my index I get the
following error:

```
[2017-10-13T11:01:03,653][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"logstash-csv", :_type=>"csv", :_routing=>nil}, 2017-10-13T09:01:03.039Z DESKTOP-hh 00.00.00.00,S], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"logstash-csv", "_type"=>"csv", "_id"=>"AV8UjolNaCIdC3w", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"[geoip.location] is defined as an object in mapping [csv] but this name is already used for a field in other types"}}}}
```

I can`t fix the above error (if this is even the end solution)

Versions:

```
Elec: 5.6.2
Logstash: 5.6.2
```

conf file:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:\Users\JOEY2\Desktop\Deelproblemen\Applicatie\Output\OutputIPInfo.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

filter {
    csv {
        separator => ","
        columns => [IP, city, country, region, org, Latitude, Longitude, SpamList, Headers]
    }
    mutate {
        convert =>{
            "Latitude" => "float"
            "Longitude" => "float"
            }
        rename => [ "Latitude", "[location][lat]", "Longitude", "[location][lon]" ]
   }
    geoip { source => "IP" }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
        index => "csv"
        document_type => "csv"
    }
}
```

mapping:

```
C:\Users\JOEY2\Downloads\curl-7.56.0-win64-ming\curl-7.56.0-win64-mingw\bin>curl -s localhost:9200/logstash-*/_mapping/?pretty
{
  "logstash-csv" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "my_type" : {
        "dynamic" : "true",
        "properties" : {
          "geoip" : {
            "dynamic" : "true",
            "properties" : {
              "location" : {
                "type" : "geo_point"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I did make a template witch I saw in a other solution:

```
PUT _template/logstash
{
  "template": "logstash-*", 
  "settings": {
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "number_of_shards": 2
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "dynamic": "true",
      "properties": {
        "geoip": {
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties": {
            "location": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            }}        }     }    }  }}
```

It feels like im missing something easy but cant figure out what it is.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful when using the last step you mentioned, as you may override the default template, and you need a proper order, which tells Elasticsearch when to apply it before or after the default.

I have came across this issue and you are right if the index starts with anything other than logstash-* it will complain about field type geo_point.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_template/csv' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "template": "csv", #this is your index name pattern
    "order": 2, #means apply after the default logstash template
    "settings": {
        #your settings go here
    },

    #add your mapping here
}'
```

Otherwise the only guaranteed solution is to have your index name starts with logstash-*

Answer (score 1):

You can't Chang the data type of the index.But you can reindex.
Refer the link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/docs-reindex.html